# liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, directory, shared, lpsolve, java.library.path

Good Morning, 
I am working with lpsolve with eclispe and in Java.

I can import correctly the program but when running it I got the exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/lp_solve/liblpsolve55j.so: liblpsolve55.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1778)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:844)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1051)
    at lpsolve.LpSolve.<clinit>(LpSolve.java:275)
    at scheduler.Main.main(Main.java:353)
```

Or, I have edited the native library path which is : `usr/lib/lp_solve.`

Can anyone help me ? 
Thank you !

Comment: how about the classpath?

Comment: the classpath is ok since I have no problem while importing lpsplve class

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Eclipse is finding liblpsolve55j.so in `/usr/lib/lp_solve` but is not looking in the same place for liblpsolve55.so.

The only workaround I found is to manually load the library with `System.load("/usr/lib/lp_solve/liblpsolve55.so")`.